# php mysql connection with three databases

Tags: php, mysql

iam using 3 different databases for my project.
it contain same password and user name. the code is

```
$con = mysql_pconnect(hostname, username, password) or die("Connection     Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(database_name, $con) or die("Error connecting to DB. " . mysql_error());

$con1 = mysql_pconnect(hostname, username, password) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(database_name, $con) or die("Error connecting to DB. " . mysql_error());

$con2 = mysql_pconnect(hostname, username, password) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(database_name, $con) or die("Error connecting to DB. " . mysql_error());
```

three database not connected properly.

Comment: What's the error? Also, you probably don't want to be using persistent connections, or even mysql_* at all. Your select_db call refers to $con on every line, you probably forgot to change that.

Comment: only exist last database connection

Comment: hostname, username, password are not valid variables in PHP. Did you check the PHP error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are possibly missing either `$` in front of variables for the connection strings:

```
$con = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Connection     Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Or you need to be sure tn use quotes around the entries.

On that note though, you should probably be using [PDO](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to connect to databases if you are writing fresh code.

Edit: Also, even though you are making new connections, you do keep using the first `$con` you define in the `mysql_select_db` statements (all use `$con` rather than `$con1`, `$con2`).

Comment: @PLB Possibly, but I would bet significant money that isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$con = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Connection     Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database_name, $con) or die("Error connecting to DB. " . mysql_error());

$con1 = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database_name1, $con1) or die("Error connecting to DB. " . mysql_error());

$con2 = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database_name2, $con2) or die("Error connecting to DB. " . mysql_error());
```

You selected first db in every selection. This is correct. Also note you will have to have 3 different database names in the 3 diff variables like this

```
$database_name="dbase";
$database_name1="dbase1";
$database_name2="dbase2";
```

Now it will connect to all 3 database instead of just one as was the case in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting to same database free times in a row, if that is your code. Probably it should be like this

```
 $con = mysql_pconnect(hostname, username, password) or die("Connection     Error: " . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(database_name, $con) or die("Error connecting to DB. " . mysql_error());

        $con1 = mysql_pconnect(hostname, username, password) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(database_name1, $con1) or die("Error connecting to DB. " . mysql_error());

        $con2 = mysql_pconnect(hostname, username, password) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
       mysql_select_db(database_name2, $con2) or die("Error connecting to DB. " . mysql_error());
```

(changed database names and connection in mysql_select_db)

Answer (score 0):

look it depends.. if you are connecting to 3 different hosts then your connection parameters may change but database name can be same..but if you are trying to connect to the same database server, you must select 3 different databases. It's simple..why would you select same database 3 times??